# Plotting multiple columns from Different Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I have been trying to make a plot in python, but I am facing challenge in syntax. I have googled but I couldn't find something suitable.

I have three data frames. Data in first dataframe is something like attached pic.

[image]

I have two more dataframes that contains one column each. One has max. temperature for past few years as shown below and another one has min. Though this 2nd DF doesn't have City Name column as DF1 has, Max temp in DF2 is for City Names mentioned in DF1 itself .

[image]

Data frame 3.

[image]

I would like to make line plot in which x axis should have City name and Y axis must be so that It can accommodate Temp from DF1, Max Temp from DF2, and Min Temp from DF3. I want to incorporate all the three line plot in the same graph.

Comment: Are the dataframes `pandas` dataframes?

Comment: @apitsch yes. These are pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create data:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"City Name": ["Toronto", "NYC"],
                    "Temp": [10, 20],
                    "Rainfall": [100, 232]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Max Temp": [20, 25]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Min Temp": [0, -10]})

# concatenate all data into one dataframe:
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)

# drop rainfall column from data:
df.drop("Rainfall", 1)

# change index to city names:
df.index = df["City Name"]

# drop city name column from data:
df.drop("City Name", 1)

plt.plot(df)
plt.legend(df.columns)
```

which would give you:

[image: Plot1]]

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame` has the builtin method [plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). If you have one data frame, you can just do something like:

```
df.plot('City Name', 'Max Temp')
```

If you have different dataframes of the same length, you can append them with `pd.concat` (there are several other options as well). I also don't know the reason but `df.plot` it doesn't show cathegorical x axis: you can correct it adding `plt.ticks`. Code sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cityname': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, dtype='U4')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Tmax': [10, 20, 30]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Tmin': [10, 20, 30]})
#linestyle dashed, color green (default is fill blue)
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1).plot('cityname', 'Tmax', linestyle='--', color='g')
plt.xticks(*zip(*enumerate(df1['cityname'])))
```